# Github permission issues - main branch behind feature

Tags: git, github

I'm having some issues with my branches in Github, I think due to using Squash and Merge. After merging a feature I started getting these error messages on my server:

```
HEAD is now at ddd new changes
error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects
fatal: failed to write object
fatal: unpack-objects failed
```

I think at some point my Main branch has gone behind a feature branch. As when I look at the branches visually I see this:

[image]

I also noticed, which you can't see in that image, that the Development branch is listed as ORIGIN/HEAD is this correct? should the Main branch be ORIGIN/HEAD?

How can I get my main branch back to being the main branch? It should be Main > Development > Feature

Comment: Shouldn't main always be behind any feature branches?

Comment: I see what you mean, I guess if they're being worked on but I'd like everything merged in at the moment

Comment: It doesn't matter which branch is where. The problem is in permissions of files/directories on the server. But how to fix it very much depends on how you use the server repository. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+error%3A+insufficient+permission+for+adding+an+object+to+repository+database+.git%2Fobjects

Comment: I'm looking at the branches because it was deploying fine on the server before, then a simple feature branch (updating css) caused this issue. The only thing I can think of is we're using squash/merge and maybe the branches aren't how they should be

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to align your branches, meaning moving the branch pointer to the latest / specific commit, you can go ahead with:

```
git branch --force <branch-name> [<new-tip-commit>]
```

Note, this is risky because it can cause missing commits in case they are not in the [] history.